# AngularJS- how to overload a function implemented within a library?

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, libraries, overloading

I am currently working on an application that has been developed in AngularJS. The application was developed internally by my company (it has gone through a number of releases, but is still being developed- adding/ improving features/ bug fixes, etc).

The application uses the [ngTagsInput](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput) library for displaying system variables and other such information.

The particular feature that I have been working on recently is trying to enable the possibility of adding more than one button to a cell in a table widget. The widget is created using an HTML form to allow the user to input its attributes (heading, columns and rows).

In its original state (when I started working on it), it was only possible to display text & system variables in the table- I added the functionality to be able to display buttons in the table cells by writing a function that would render each element (text, separated by a comma) entered into the 'rows' field on the HTML form as a button if the first character of that element was a `:` (the following characters would have to be a string that represented a valid path to a page- i.e. like a hyperlink).

I now want to extend this functionality so that it is possible to add multiple buttons to a single table cell. However, although I have written the code to do this, I have found that it doesn't actually work as I expect it to, because of some apparent limitations of the underlying functions used (provided by the [ngTagsInput](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput) library).

The limitation that's causing me the problem, is that 'tags' are only displayed correctly as 'tags' when they are selected from the [ngTagsInput](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput) library's autocomplete list feature (and since my navigation buttons are built on the same feature, they are also only displayed as buttons whens selected from the autocomplete list), i.e. as the user types into the 'rows' field on the HTML form for the table widget setup, an 'autocomplete' list is displayed showing matching tags/ pages- this list is filtered as the user continues to type.

A tag or page is only displayed as a tag or page element (rather than as text) when the user selects it from the autocomplete list.

Since I now want to display multiple tags/ page buttons in a single table cell, I need to be able to select more than one element from the autocomplete list at a time- but this is not currently possible due to how the [ngTagsInput](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput) library has been written.

I have investigated exactly what's happening, and have identified the functions being used by the library as part of this autocomplete feature to display the tags & buttons as tags & buttons (rather than as text- which is how they're initially typed).

I am using a local copy of the library, but obviously don't want to make changes to the library itself if I can help it.

How can I overload the functions provided by the library in the cases where I need to alter its behaviour from within my own code?

For example, the `autocomplete` directive has an `addSuggestion()` function defined within the `link()` function of its `return` statement- how could I overload this in particular instances within my code, so that rather than adding a single tag & resetting the suggestion list when it's called, it could add multiple tags before resetting the suggestion list?

**Edit**

The `addSuggestion()` function is defined in the library with:

```
tagsInput.directive('autoComplete', ["$document", "$timeout", "$sce", "$q", "tagsInputConfig", "tiUtil", function($document, $timeout, $sce, $q, tagsInputConfig, tiUtil) {
    function SuggestionList(loadFn, options, events) {
        ...
    }

    function scrollToElement(root, index) {
        ...
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^tagsInput',
        scope { source: '&' },
        templateUrl: 'ngTagsInput/auto-complete.html',
        controller: ["$scope", "$element", "$attrs", function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            ...
            $scope.suggestionList = new SuggestionList($scope.source, $scope.options, $scope.events);

            this.registerAutocompleteMatch = function() {
                return {
                    getOptions: function() {
                        return $scope.options;
                    },
                    getQuery: function() {
                        return $scope.suggestionList.query;
                    }
                };
            };
        }],
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, tagsInputCtrl) {
            var hotkeys = [KEYS.enter, KEYS.tab, KEYS.escape, KEYS.up, KEYS.down],
                suggestionList = scope.suggestionList,
                tagsInput = tagsInputCtrl.registerAutocomplete(),
                options = scope.options,
                events = scope.events,
                shouldLoadSuggestions;

            options.tagsInput = tagsINput.getOptions();
            ...
            scope.addSuggestion = function() {
                var added = false;
                if(suggestionList.selected) {
                    tagsInput.addTag(angular.copy(suggestionList.selected));
                    suggestionList.reset();
                    tagsInput.focusInput();

                    added = true;
                }
                return added;
            };
            ...
            events.on('suggestion-selected', function(index) {
                scrollToElement(element, index);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: How about scling this issue down to a condensed version...far too much to read

Comment: The descriptions work only for those who are already accustomed with the code. Please, don't describe the code, post it instead. A requirement for SO questions is http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have posted the code for the function that I want to overload.